# JMeter understanding ramp-up

Tags: performance, testing, jmeter

This is the configuration of my test plan thread properties:

```
Number of Threads (users): 100
Ramp-up Period (in seconds): 10
Loop Count : Forever
Delay thread creation until needed: No
Scheduler: No
```

I ran the test overnight with the total duration of 14 hours and 7 minutes (approximately 50820 seconds). After loading the jtl file, The number of samples shown in summary report is 1050975. I tried to compute but I can't understand how it came up with that many sample.

If Ramp-up Period is the time taken by JMeter to create the number of threads per iteration and if the duration of the test is 50820 seconds, then I should have 508200 samples only ( 50820/10 * 100 ). I do not know how or if Loop Count affects this.

Comment: In addition to the answers; I usually set the ramp-up period the same as the number of threads, i.e. add a new thread every second. Just to be sure I'm not doing too much at once.

Comment: The number of samples is also a function of response time of your samples. So if your samples are served in 0.5 seconds, you will have 2 samples per second. After 10 seconds, all 100 threads will be full throttle and you will be seeing 200 samples per second. And hence higher number of samples in give time duration. I think you are assuming only 1 sample will be requested per second, which is not true.

Answer (score 91, accepted):

The ramp-up in the [Thread Group](http://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/component_reference.html#Thread_Group) is the time JMeter should take to start the total number of threads. In your situation this means that every 0.1 second a new thread starts giving 100 running threads after 10 seconds. These 100 threads perform your test iterations back-to-back, so after the ramp-up 100 threads run continously for the duration of the test.

Comment: Why do we need ramp up? cant we start all at once? I mean what is the reason people choose to have some time to ramp up?

Comment: Useful for testing auto-scaling - e.g. for *most* websites, it's unlikely that you're going to go from 0 to 100 concurrent users instantly.  It's more likely that concurrent users will gradually increase (and thereby give the auto-scaling system time to respond).  Ramp-up enables this scenario to be tested.

Answer (score 35):

**Ramp-up Period** - The time frame (in seconds) for all requests to start. All the threads specified in the **`Number of Threads`** input will start within **`Ramp-up period`**.

For instance:

**100 threads and 100 seconds ramp-up:** each second JMeter will start **1 Thread** until all threads are started by the time the **100 seconds** are up.

**100 threads and 50 seconds ramp-up:** each second **2 Threads** are started.

**100 threads and 200 seconds ramp-up:** every **2 seconds**, **1 Thread** is started.

Now,

The sample or request generation is a different concept than **Thread generation**.In you case, 100 threads were up within 10 seconds.The key factor here is the [Throughput](http://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/glossary.html#Throughput).
As per JMeter glossary:

> Throughput is calculated as requests/unit of time. The time is
>   calculated from the start of the first sample to the end of the last
>   sample. This includes any intervals between samples, as it is supposed
>   to represent the load on the server.
>
> The formula is: Throughput =
>   (number of requests) / (total time).

Here the Number of Executed Samples or Requests are **`1050975`** and the Test duration is **`50820`** seconds. So this is related to Throughput.The output **`1050975`** requests in **`50820s`** mean the **Average Throughput** throughout your test was approximate **`20.5/s`**.

To take control over `Throughput` or `Transactions per second` there are very handy JMeter plugins called [Constant Throughput Timer](http://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/component_reference.html#Constant_Throughput_Timer).

> Constant Throughput Timer introduces variable pauses, calculated to
>   keep the total throughput (in terms of samples per minute) as close as
>   possible to a given figure. Of course, the throughput will be lower if
>   the server is not capable of handling it, or if other timers or
>   time-consuming test elements prevent it.

Comment: Thank you for details. what is best value to take for Ramp Up time field in case you want to run forever loop and want to maintain 5 sec ramp up time ?

Answer (score 12):

The ramp-up period tells JMeter how long to take to “ramp-up” to the full number of threads.

@Little Chicken
Understanding 1 is correct.

If 10 threads are used, and the ramp-up period is 10 seconds, then JMeter will take 10 seconds to get all 10 threads up and running.

Each thread will start 1 second after the previous thread was begun.

Answer (score 9):

For Example

1. 1000 target threads with 1000 seconds ramp-up: JMeter will add one
   user each second
2. 1000 target threads with 100 seconds ramp-up: JMeter will add 10
   users each second
3. 1000 target threads with 50 seconds ramp-up: JMeter will add 20
   users each second

Answer (score 4):

The ramp-up period tells JMeter how long to take to "ramp-up" to the full number of threads chosen. If 10 threads are used, and the ramp-up period is 100 seconds, then JMeter will take 100 seconds to get all 10 threads up and running. Each thread will start 10 (100/10) seconds after the previous thread was begun. If there are 30 threads and a ramp-up period of 120 seconds, then each successive thread will be delayed by 4 seconds.

Answer (score 2):

**This property tells JMeter how long to delay between starting each user.**

For example, if you enter a Ramp-Up Period of 5 seconds, JMeter will
 finish starting all of your users by the end of the 5 seconds. So, if
 we have 5 users and a 5 second Ramp-Up Period, then the delay between
 starting users would be 1 second (5 users / 5 seconds = 1 user per
 second). If you set the value to 0, then JMeter will immediately start
 all of your users.

Answer (score 1):

Understanding 1: is correct 
The ramp-up period tells JMeter how long to take to "ramp-up" to the full number of threads chosen. If 10
threads are used, and the ramp-up period is 100 seconds, then JMeter will take 100 seconds to get all 10
threads up and running. Each thread will start 10 (100/10) seconds after the previous thread was begun. If there
are 30 threads and a ramp-up period of 120 seconds, then each successive thread will be delayed by 4 seconds

Answer (score 1):

Ramp up Period: Rate at which the users will be onborded to start the trasaction.

In jMeter, with 10 users if you give a ramp up time of 20, then 1 user will start executing the plan every 2 seconds.

Answer (score 0):

When you have , say a 100 threads , you can give a ramp up of 10 seconds. But if your total threads are only 5 or 10, you have to give 0 ramp up seconds. Because it is then common for your application to get 5 hits at the exact second. So keep this in mind. If you think it is possible to get 10 hits at the same second, then give ramp up as 0 for the thread group and give an infinite loop and define the duration