# Jmeter - timer does not work between threads in the same http request

Tags: jmeter

I have a http request with a BSF postprocessor script where I try to collect some data from the request.   I have 10 users who call this request. I want to add a small delay between each request and I tried using a constant timer. The problem I have is, sometimes 2 or 3 HTTP requests are executed at the same time and that causes some logic disturbances in my postprocessor script. I tried using a constant throughput timer and still I end up with the same result. What is the correct way to send requests at constant time intervals?

Comment: Are you talking about threads when you say 'users'? if this is the case, I think that setting a ramp-up period should work for you. Check [this other question](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/17288545/jmeter-understanding-ramp-up)

Comment: Can you be more specific about "logic disturbances" in the post processor? This seems to be an issue in the first place.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A timer is specific to each thread so what you are tring to do will not work.

If you want to ensure your query is only executed by 1 user then use Critical Section Controller:

- https://m.youtube.com/watch?v=HVVyTvoTmdc
- http://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/component_reference.html#Critical_Section_Controller

Comment: how do i do that? I don't see a "accept answer' button

Answer (score 0):

Thanks for the responses. I was finally able to achieve it just by increasing the ramp-up time. Thanks Mario for your quick response.

Comment: I don't think it's the right way to do it, as if your response takes time, you will end up having 2 requests sent at the same time, not also if your test  lasts, you will end up having 2 or more requests triggered at the same time