# How to calculate samples of JMeter aggregate report

Tags: jmeter

I started 80 virtual users in 600 seconds, selected forever in loop count and run 40 minutes.

Then I confused about samples in JMeter aggregate report.

80 threads finished in 600 seconds and run 40 minutes. There are 4 loop counts and 320 samples, but there are 5,000 more samples.

[image]

[image]

How can I calculate samples of the JMeter aggregate report?

Comment: What is exactly your problem ? What did you expect ?

Comment: @ UBIK LOAD PACK  I don't  figure out how jmeter works  in  40 minutes, and  if  loop forever option was set,   threads   started before don't exit  and  send requests constantly ?

Comment: @wonbin2011, I am also stuck with similar issue. But what is 320 samples and where did you mention this value in Jmeter. Thanks.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The aggregate report seems to be generating the correct results.

Suppose, you run the test for single user [say user1] instead of 80 and for 'Loop Count' set to 1 (instead of forever) even then the single user will increase the samples count to (1*320*4 = 1,280) and in your case you are executing the test for 80 users so it is expected that the samples count can reach to #102,400 (80*4*320) if all 80 users executed the scenario at least once.

I am in a software qa company & working on JMeter for quite long time and would recommend a couple of things that can help you to organize your script in a better way which can further help to easily understand your results:

- When you have multiple child samplers for any request [say login request] then its good to keep all the child samplers related to that request in a single 'Transaction Controller' element and check 'Generate parent sample' checkbox.[image]
- Give unique name to the samplers to identify them easily during failures & also you will see unique samplers name in JMeter report
- Clear the previous test results [or listeners] before starting a new test otherwise your new test result gets appended to the last test results

Comment: yes, it is a  login request and  there are many  child requests. i put multiple child samplers in one transaction  controller,  and  cleared  the previous results,  thank you so so so  much from china beijing  !!!

Comment: btw, if 'Loop Count' set to 1 ,  how does the ramp-up period  value works ?

Comment: reference link:https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17288545/jmeter-understanding-ramp-up?rq=1

Comment: The ramp-up time is independent of loop count and only related to the users count:
Suppose, you are running the test for 10 users with ramp-up set to 5 and loop count set to any value [say 5]. when you start the test then 2 users get logged in after each second [users count/ramp-up = 2] and after ramp-up time [5 second in this case], all your users [10 in this case] will be up & running the test and the scenario will continue to execute in the loop as per the value set in Loop Count field.

Let me know if you have any further question.

Comment: yes , when loop count forever was set, the threads would not exit  until the test was stop . the ramp-up time is independent of loop count and the thread user is independent of  sending requst numbers