# incresed time gap between each data

Tags: api, performance, testing, websocket, load-testing

I am passing data from file on server with gap of 1 sec between each data. But when I am putting load from jmeter or connecting more connections the gap is increasing to 4 sec why? Is it server issue or performance issue

I tried by restarting service and putting less load but facing same problem

Answer (score 0):

If the "gap" (whatever it is) becoming 4x times higher under the load and only under the load it might indicate one of the following:

1. Try increasing your load **[gradually](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17288545/jmeter-understanding-ramp-up)**, this way you will be able to detemine the saturation poing and know the maximum supported number of users, the number of users when response time starts growing, the number of users where errors start occurring, etc.
2. Incorrect configuration of the system under test (i.e. small [connection pool](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Connection_pool)). Inspect your application and middleware configuration and ensure that it corresponds to the anticipated load
3. Lack of resources in terms of CPU, RAM, Network, Disk, etc. The system under test must have enough headroom to operate, in case of lack of any of above you will experience increased response times at least. It can be checked using i.e. [JMeter PerfMon Plugin](https://www.blazemeter.com/blog/jmeter-performance-metrics)
4. Repeat your test with [profiler tool](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/List_of_performance_analysis_tools) telemetry enabled. It will give you the exact information regarding where the system spends the most time while processing the incoming request so you would be able to localize and optimize the responsible piece of code or [slow SQL query](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/slow-query-log.html) or whatever.